# my site page/post can not visit, showing error

Tags: database, wordpress

I am running a site by Wordpress. My site home page is fine, there have no problem to visit. But other page like, post, category, page do not show. When going to visit, than show this message "

> Not Found
>       The requested URL /terms-condition/ was not found on this server.
>       Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Few facts: Few hours ago i got a email that, some one add google web masters tool (a txt file) and a xml file to my site cpnael. I don't know how he/she got the access of my cpanel. May be He/she try to add few content with my site illegally. After that, i remove those and change cpanel password. also i try to increase security by "All In One WP Security" plugin. may be this time something happen with wp table prefix or database. after that i can not visit other page or post. than i removed this plugin from my wp dashboard. But still i can not visit it.

Basically, after setting "All In One WP Security" plugin, i face the problem.

My site url is: http://cleaningservicetips.com/

I can visit home page only not others. How can i get solution?

Thanks in advance.
Al Amin

Comment: goto admin-panel->settings->permalink and then click on update twice and then check again your links

Comment: everything seems ok. have a look up your broken links

Comment: Thank you very much, I was to much worried after someone to get access of cpanel. Yes now okay after checking permalink. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your permalinks section in WordPress and click update.

Found in *WordPress > Settings > Permalinks*

This will refresh the permalinks / enable the SEO friendly URL scheme.

Furthermore, you may want to reference this article for more of an in-depth look at WP permalinks. https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks